# Are Fargate tasks able to be hosted in public subnets?

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

When creating a Service, under VPC subnets, the tooltip says "Choose the subnets in this VPC that the task scheduler should consider for placement. Only private subnets are supported at this time".

[image: Configure VPC]

However AWS documentation and diagrams show Fargate tasks in public subnets.

[image: Fargate task in public subnet]

Can somebody please explain if I am misunderstanding these seemingly conflicting messages?

Comment: Yes it is certainly possible to have Fargate Tasks in Public Subnets. Here is a blog(https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/task-networking-in-aws-fargate/) which also explains the same.